# Exchange 2010 and AD Master at once on Windows 2008 Server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, exchange-2010

Reading the Microsoft tech notes on Exchange 2010 configuration, I learned that it is not recommended to have the same server act as an AD domain controller and Exchange 2010 server at once. I have a Windows 2008 Server with Exchange on it and was hoping to do exactly that so the old Windows 2003 servers could be retired and all Windows services consolidated on a single server. Partly because we are limited in the amount of power in the server room and more equipment is being added soon.

Please give me your opinions on this. The server is handling about 50 users, so at least the load on it is not extreme. I am aware that it is not possible to change the AD role without reinstalling the whole thing. Given the configuration quirks the 2008 and Exchange 2010 server suffers from years of upgrading servers without cleaning up, it will likely be a good thing to configure the whole thing from scratch.

Of course the entire thing cannot take more than 24 hours, that's a bonus challenge. I do have other PCs available so I could set up a temporary server installation to take over for the main server as that one is being configured.

I appreciate your opinions,

Thanks

M

Comment: You want an opinion - don't do it. Seriously. It's not only not recommended, it's unsupported. If you *really* want everything on one box, look at SBS - that's designed specifically to house everything in a supported manner.

Comment: Use VMware or the virtualization tool of your choice and lab this out. I would expect that you may run into limitations with permissions and such, maybe even collisions of roles, but I'm betting it can be done. Whether its a good idea or not, that's another story.

Answer (score 2):

To echo Ben, it does sound like you want to get SBS. With SBS 2011 Std you get up to 75 users and devices (not sure if that's concurrent or not; consult your vendor).  [Licensing FAQ](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/5/C/45CD1DC6-9204-44DD-999B-24B50A9144B6/SBS%202011_Licensing_FAQ.pdf) (pdf warning).

SBS is its own beast and does require some getting used to, but it is the recommended way for SMBs with small infrastructures to go.